# Botte de/à/en cuir

Tags: grammaire

Je voudrais savoir comme on peut créer de nouveaux mots en français à partir de deux autres mots ou plus. J'ai déjà remarqué que la preposition *de* ou la preposition *à* sont souvent utilisées en l'occurence, par exemple: *pomme de pin, arbre de Noël.*

En anglais, c'est facile parce que on peut faire de nouveaux mots  anglais comme ça: *pear tree, Christmas tree, mountain goat, book shelf.*

Comment: Une leçon sur les **noms composés** : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj9Db58devU, il y en a d'autres (par ex : https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/compound-noun-plurals/)...

Comment: un arbre qui produit des pommes, c'est un pommier; qui produit des poires, c'est un poirier; qui produit des chérimoles même (cherimoyas en anglais), c'est un chérimolier.

Comment: Les prépositions ("à ou "de") sont nécessaires pour lier 2 noms. Les appositions sont les exceptions très minoritaires à cette règle, par exemle une "femme enfant" ou une "mère courage".

Comment: Globalement il n'y a pas de règle malheureusement, chaque paire de substantifs a sa façon particulière d'être associée.

Comment: D'habitude, quand il s'agit du matériel on utilise *en* (*bottes en cuir, maison en bois*... mais *tarte aux pommes*)